# Ubuntu 12.04 blanks the display unless the mouse is moved at least once after boot

Tags: 12.04, display, suspend

I am trying to deploy a bunch of machines without any KB/mouse, only a display.  Their job is to launch Firefox and immediately display a URL full screen.  Everything is working except that the screens go blank ten minutes after boot unless the mouse is moved at least one time.  Once you move the mouse, the display will stay on forever (tested to five days).

I have disabled all lock/sleep options in the UI.  Additionally, I've spent hours trying different solutions from this and other forums and various other Linux admins I work with, and found no success.  I'll outline what's been tried so far below (and I'm sure I'll miss other things that have also been tried, there have been a lot of things attempted).

I even attempted to use xdotool to move the mouse right after the desktop loads, but that does NOT prevent sleep.  It only prevents sleep if I move a real mouse or move it over VNC.

Tried:

xset s noblank
xset -dpms ; xset s off
setterm -powersave off -blank 0
setterm -blank 0 -powersave off -powerdown 0
xset s off

Comment: Have you tried other window managers or desktop environments and if so, is the behavior consistent? Perhaps install Lubuntu and try to reproduce the issue and if it's present, strip down to a relatively bare Openbox session and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I use synergy, so I can use one keyboard and mouse with two PC's (one windows7 and one with ubuntu 13.10) it might not be what you need it for but a side effect is that the power options and the screensavers are synced, so one will not fall asleep or activate screen saver unless the other does aswell. when i accidentilly leave the mouse active on the win7 screen neither PC will fall asleep, no matter how long the mouse or keys have not been moved. I seem to have the opposite error to you but it might be helpful in your case :) of course this will only help if they are all under the same network.